# How to extract values from xml file with namespaces?

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, xml-namespaces, elementtree

I have the xml file shown below, that has namespaces, for which I'm trying to extract the values of `Node24`

My current code is below, that is not printing anything:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

filename = 'ifile.xml'
tree = ET.parse(filename)
root = tree.getroot()

for neighbor in root.iter('Node24'):
    print(neighbor)
```

My expected output would be:

```
03-c34ko
04-c64ko
07-c54ko
```

The is the ifile.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<data-main-43:DATAMAINXZ123 xmlns="https://example.com/DATA-MAIN-XZ123" xmlns:data-gen="https://example.com/DATA-GEN" xmlns:data-main-43="https://example.com/DATA-MAIN-XZ123" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2011/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="https://example.com/DATA-MAIN-XZ123 data-main-ir21-12.1.xsd">
  <MAINXZ123FileHeader>
    <DATAGenSchemaVersion>2.4</DATAGenSchemaVersion>
    <DATAMAINXZ123SchemaVersion>12.1</DATAMAINXZ123SchemaVersion>
  </MAINXZ123FileHeader>
  <Node1>
    <Node2>WTRT DDK</Node2>
    <Node3>XYZW</Node3>
    <Node4>
      <Node5>
        <Node6>XYZW882</Node6>
        <Node5Type>Ter</Node5Type>
        <Node5Data>
          <Node9>
            <Node10>
              <Node11>2019-02-18</Node11>
              <Node12>
                <Node13>
                  <Node14>
                    <Node15>Ermso</Node15>
                    <Node16>
                      <PrimaryNode16>
                        <Node18>19.32</Node18>
                        <Node18>12.11</Node18>
                      </PrimaryNode16>
                      <SecondaryNode16>
                        <Node18>82.97</Node18>
                        <Node18>12.41</Node18>
                      </SecondaryNode16>
                    </Node16>
                    <Node20>Muuatippw</Node20>
                  </Node14>
                </Node13>
              </Node12>
              <Node21>
                <Node22>
                  <Node23>
                    <Node24>03-c34ko</Node24>
                    <Node24>04-c64ko</Node24>
                    <Node24>07-c54ko</Node24>
                  </Node23>
                  <Node26Node22EdgeAgent>
                    <Node26>jjkksonem</Node26>
                    <PrimaryNode18DEANode26>
                      <Node18>2.40</Node18>
                    </PrimaryNode18DEANode26>
                  </Node26Node22EdgeAgent>
                </Node22>
              </Node21>
              <Node28>
                <Node29>
                  <Node30>false</Node30>
                  <Node31>true</Node31>
                </Node29>
              </Node28>
            </Node10>
          </Node9>
        </Node5Data>
      </Node5>
    </Node4>
  </Node1>
</data-main-43:DATAMAINXZ123>
```

How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/55655108/407651

Comment: Thanks for the link shared. I'll check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the [duplicate mzjn referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55655108/parsing-xml-with-elementtrees-iter-isnt-finding-my-tags-when-i-pass-a-specif), just add the namespace uri to the element name...

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

filename = 'ifile.xml'
tree = ET.parse(filename)
root = tree.getroot()

for neighbor in root.iter('{https://example.com/DATA-MAIN-XZ123}Node24'):
    print(neighbor.text)
```

Note: I also added `.text` to `neighbor` so you'd get the requested result.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using regular expression so this is an alternative answer.
I converted the xml into string then search for all strings between Node24

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import re

filename = 'ifile.xml'
tree = ET.parse(filename)
root = tree.getroot()
xml_str = ET.tostring(root) 
for s in re.findall(r'ns0:Node24>(.*?)</ns0:Node24', str(xml_str)):
    print(s)
```

Result:

```
03-c34ko
04-c64ko
07-c54ko
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It seems to work. But if I'd like to extract more elements, I'll need to change the node within the regex? another question, what does mean `ns0:...`?

Comment: Why bother parsing as XML when you could just do `open("ifile.xml").read()` and pretend that there is no default namespace? In most cases, using regexes on XML or HTML is not a good idea. https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/407651

Comment: @mzjn I don't get your point hehe. How would you suggest to extract the values of `Node24`? If regex is not a good idea...

Comment: @mzjn I saw it. In that link they talk about that is not good to parse using regex, others in that thread say "don't listen to these guys", but there is no solution for my question there.